# Realizar un buscador en tiempo real en el que se pueda pinchar en los resultados y obtener su id

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

He estado buscando por stack overflow respuestas a esta pregunta y no lo encuentro. Si es cierto que hay múltiples preguntas referidas a buscadores en tiempo real, pero ninguna en la que se pueda clicar en los resultados. Yo ya tengo el buscador realizado, pero quiero que cuando pinches en los resultado ocurra algo. Como en Instagram cuando buscas a un usuario, te salen varias opciones y cuando pulsas te lleva al perfil de esa persona.
Además, me gustaría saber cómo puedo obtener el id del botón que he pulsado. Muchas gracias de antemano.
Esto es lo que tengo hecho:
Este el el html del buscador y el script:

```
<div id="lateral2">
              <h1>Buscador</h1>
              <div class="form-1-2">
                <label for="buscador">Buscar:</label>
                <input type="text" name="buscador" id="buscador"></input>
              </div>
              <div id="datos">
              </div>

        <script>
          $(buscar_datos());
          function buscar_datos(consulta){
            $.ajax({
              url: 'buscar.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: {consulta: consulta},
            })
            .done(function(respuesta){
              $("#datos").html(respuesta);
            })
            .fail(function(){
              console.log("error");
            })
          }
          $(document).on('keyup', '#buscador', function(){
            var valor = $(this).val();
            if(valor != ""){
              buscar_datos(valor);
            }else{
              buscar_datos();
            }
          });
        </script>
```

Y este es el archivo buscar.php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    '',
    'crapping',
);

$salida = "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM grupos";
if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT g.nombre, u.nombre FROM grupos AS g INNER JOIN usuarios AS u WHERE u.nombre LIKE '%".$q."%' OR g.nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$resultado = $conn->query($query);
if($resultado->num_rows>0){
    $salida.="<table class='tabla_datos'>
                <tbody>";

    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $salida.="<tr>
                <td><button id=fila1>".$fila['nombre']."</button></td>
                </tr>";
    }
    
    $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    echo $salida;
    
} else{
    $salida.="No hay todavia ningún grupo que se llame así. Puedes buscar por otro nombre o crear uno.";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<script>
    const fila1 = document.getElementById('fila1');
    fila1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('boton funciona');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ya que estás usando jQuery, te recomiendo la extensión [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) y, de preferencia, desde PHP devuelve solo un arreglo, no código HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los resultados no son algo mas que una capa del que creas en el DOM o que muestras y rellenas con los resultados devueltos. En tu caso esta ben usas una tabla y devuelves esto desde el PHP para insertarlo en el DOM con jQuery

```
<tr><td><button id=fila1>".$fila['nombre']."</button></td></tr>
```

Añádele a  una clase quedando así

```
<button id=fila1 class="button_buscar_user">".$fila['nombre']."</button>
```

entonces el código en jQuery seria algo así adaptándolo un poco a tu código

```
$('body').on('click' , '.button_buscar_user' , function() {
  
  // Sacar el id del botón, apuntando al propio objeto boton actual con this
  
  var IDbotton = $(this).attr('id')
  
  // Lo cual hará que jQuery almacene el "file1"que coloca PHP en el ID del boton

  // Ejecutar un ajax con $.ajax() que haga lo que quieras cuando el evento click se dispara sobre el botón

  // Tambien podrias usar un href

  location.href = '/user_'+IDbotton

  // Con esto podrías mover toda la pagina directamente a la vista del usuario que tienes, en todo caso puedes también usar el ajax para traer los datos que estimes pertinente o hacer lo que quieras como darle información al usuario antes de acceder a su perfil y cosas por ese estilo

})
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me ha funcionado muy bien.